# why is my os x hhd available on my ubuntu partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I am running ubuntu on a macbook pro. Recently I restored my os x partition using a backup, and now I notice that in my Recovery HD and my Macintosh HD are both showing up in my Ubuntu in the /media folder. I'm worried that this might be a security concern, or that they might accidently get unmounted.

Does anyone know how to make them unavailable to my ubuntu partition? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Possibly remove them from /etc/fstab

May not work, and I am not responsible for any damage you cause to your system.

Comment: LoL =) gotta say this made me laugh...